# jqgrid post request data json

Tags: json, post, jqgrid

My grid data read is configured for use json format.
This is the configuration

```
    url:"devitem.json",
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",

    ajaxGridOptions: {
      type    : 'post',
      async   : false,
      error   : function() { alert('Something bad happened. Stopping');},
    },

    jsonReader : {
      root        : "rows",
      page        : "page",
      total       : "total",
      records     : "records",
      repeatitems : true,
      cell        : "cell",
      id          : "0",
      userdata    : "userdata",
    },
```

The read request from client send always parameters in this format:

_search=false&nd=1317286048991&rows=25&page=1&sidx=device_id&sord=asc&totalrows=100
How I can convert it to json format ?

I have also set the postData option

```
postData    : JSON.stringify({"dev_post_reqtype":"read","dev_post_devndx":"1","dev_post_reccount":"55"}),
```

It work but obiuovsly cannot be changed

I have this problem with pager. For testing after change the page number I call this function

```
    function DEVpager_event(pgevent) {

 var page = jQuery("#DEVtbl").getGridParam('page');
  alert (pgevent+page) ;

// changed devndx for test only
var jdata = JSON.stringify({"dev_post_reqtype":"read","dev_post_devndx":"25","dev_post_reccount":"55"}) ;
```

jQuery("#DEVtbl").jqGrid('setGridParam', 'postData', jdata);
    } ;

page is changed with my selection but postData don't change 
thanks for help

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correct your problem you should use [serializeGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) in about the following form:

```
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

If you need send some additional data to the server you can use *additionally*

```
postData: {
    dev_post_reqtype: "read",
    dev_post_devndx: "1",
    dev_post_reccount: "55"
}
```

or

```
postData: {
    dev_post_reqtype: "read",
    dev_post_devndx: 1,
    dev_post_reccount: 55
}
```

depend on the type of `dev_post_devndx` and `dev_post_reccount` properties which you need (string or integer).

Comment: Thanks! Someone should mark this as the answer. It works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

The documentations of jqGrid... probably the worst I have ever seen

Try with this example:

```
    $("#wlistt").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerwlist',
        {  add: true, edit: true, del: true },
        {// settings for edit
                        afterShowForm:afterShowEdit, 
                        afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
                        beforeSubmit:validateData,
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        closeAfterEdit: true
                } 
                ,{// settings for add
                        afterShowForm:afterShowAdd, 
                        afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
                        beforeSubmit:validateData,
                        closeAfterAdd: true,
                        closeAfterEdit: true
                }
                ,{} // settings for delete
        );

    } 
}
function afterShowEdit(formId) {
            alert('show_edit');         
}
function afterShowAdd(formId) {

        alert('show_add');
}
function processAddEdit(formId) {

        alert('proc_add');
}
function validateData(formId) {

        alert('val_dat');
}
```